# JavaScript convert boolean to string according to PHP's practice

Tags: javascript, boolean, tostring

Is there some way to convert a boolean to string in the same way as PHP does it?

So that `false` becomes `''` (empty string) and `true` becomes `1`.

As of right now, `true.toString()` becomes `"true"` and `false.toString()` becomes `"false"`, not what I want.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the ternary operator? `some_var = some_var ? 1 : '';`

Comment: @Marcel I'm wondering if there is some casting solution.

Comment: Personally, I would say that the way PHP handles this is inconsistent, as it should produce 0 for false and 1 for true (I know that an empty string evals to false, but still).

Answer (score 2):

```
Boolean.prototype.toPHPString = function() { 
  return this ? '1' : '' 
};
```

will give you

```
true.toPHPString() // => '1'
false.toPHPString() // => ''
(1 == 1).toPHPString() // => '1'
```